How to handle App links without creating a new task when using singleTop in MainActivity?
I am working on an Android app that has multiple activities, and my MainActivity is declared with launchMode="singleTop" because I need to handle the app’s app linking logic.
Here’s the problem I’m facing:

When my app is already open, and I click on an app link (from Gmail app), it opens the MainActivity in a new task.
Since my app has several activities, I can't use "singleTask" for the launchMode, as that would interfere with the navigation flow across other activities.

I would like to know if there is any way to ensure that my app always opens in the same task when handling app links, instead of creating a new task, while keeping the singleTop launchMode in MainActivity.
Question:
Is there any solution that ensures my app handles app links without creating a new task, while maintaining the singleTop behavior for MainActivity?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!
I have tried using "singleTask", but if the app is open on another activity, I cannot return to that activity.
